# Bootstrap Button Group Selected on Load

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a boostrap button group toggle. It says male|female.  On page load it shows male so I want it to be toggled/selected to male on page load. Does anyone know how to do this simply?!

```
<div class="btn-group gender-button" role="group" aria-label="...">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-target="male-socks">Male</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-target="female-socks">Female</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using button? Do you this http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/ ??

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using buttons use radio buttons (I assume u mean that as ur question is not very clear)

```html
 <div class="btn-group gender-button" role="group" aria-label="...">
   <input type="radio" class="btn btn-default" data-target="male-socks">Male</input>
   <input type="radio" class="btn btn-default" data-target="female-socks">Female</input>
</div>
```

*Looking for something else , please let me know*